# Why is Tcl variable command always return an empty string?

Tags: function, variables, namespaces, tcl

See code below:

```
namespace eval foo {
    variable bar 5
    proc getBar {} {
    variable bar
    }
    proc getRetBar {} {
    variable bar
    return $bar
    }
}
puts "\"[ foo::getBar ]\""
puts "\"[ foo::getRetBar ]\""
exit
```

It outputs:

```
""
"5"
```

Why does it not return the variable value, just like the set command would?
Why does it always return an empty string? If I want to access namespace variables through procedure, and not by accessing them directly, it makes the code slightly longer. Not a major issue, but a little annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way the command is defined. It makes sense, because if given an odd number of arguments, the last one is a name that will be declared as a namespace variable but need not exist. If it doesn't exist, what value should `variable` return?

Still, it's no hassle to write a single-command getter procedure (assuming the variable exists):

```
proc getBar {} {
    set [namespace current]::bar
}
```

Or you could use a TclOO object (note that you need a setter to initialize it):

```
oo::object create foo
# -> ::foo
oo::objdefine foo variable bar
oo::objdefine foo method setBar v {set bar $v}
oo::objdefine foo method getBar {} {set bar}
foo setBar 5
# -> 5
puts "\"[foo getBar]\""
# => "5"
```

You can define the object in one call, if you prefer:

```
oo::objdefine foo {
    variable bar
    method setBar v {set bar $v}
    method getBar {} {set bar}
}
```

Documentation: [namespace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/namespace.htm), [oo::objdefine](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm), [oo::object](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/object.htm), [variable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/variable.htm)

Answer (score 2):

The `proc` command returns an empty string by default. When a procedure is invoked, the procedure's return value is the value specified in a `return` command. If the procedure does not execute an explicit `return`, then its return value is the value of the last command executed in the procedure's body.

**The fun part here is that `variable` command never returns any value. It just creates/initializes/modifies a namespace variable.**

```
% namespace eval foo {
    variable bar 5
    proc getBar {} {
        variable bar
    }
}
```

If the `variable` command is executed inside a Tcl procedure, it creates local variables linked to the corresponding namespace variables and therefore these variables are listed by `info vars`.

```
% info vars foo::*
::foo::bar
% set foo::bar; # Getting the 'bar' value
5
% variable foo::bar 10; # Note that it does not return any value as such.
%
% set foo::bar
10
%
```

Since there is no implicit/explicit return value in the procedure `getBar`, it is returning the empty string which is the default.

Reference : [variable](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/variable.htm), [proc](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/proc.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It works that way because that's how it was implemented and documented, which is to say that it is a relatively arbitrary decision. However it is a decision that occurred nearly 20 years ago, and we see no particular reason to revisit it. Who knows what (OK, probably quite ill-advised) code would be broken?

That said, the main use of `variable` is with a single argument. What would be the result in this case? It's even used when the variable concerned does not exist: there is no sensible result possible at all, and unlike `set` it is *not* an error to do that (it allocates some structures in the namespace if necessary, and binds a local variable if in a procedure). The result you ask for would also make little sense when we have four arguments: why would the last thing to be set be privileged this way? The `set` command rejects this, and so does not need to deal with the philosophical consequences.

It is better to let `variable` continue to do what it currently does. It might be longer to write an explicit read as well, but it is also considerably clearer as to what the *intention* of the code is, and that is a thoroughly good thing over the somewhat longer term.